# Power Query: Parameterize the Tables a Merge Query Operates on

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I am using Power Query in Excel for Microsoft 365.

I am trying to create a merge query to perform an inner join. The kicker is that I need to parameterize the tables to be joined.

I have a text parameter named `MyParam`.

Please consider this M Language code:

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(Text.Combine({MyParam, "_Table_1"}), {"Join Field"}, Text.Combine({MyParam, "_Table_2"}), {"Join Field"}, Text.Combine({MyParam, "_Table_2"}), JoinKind.Inner),
...
```

If, for example, I set `MyParam` to "foo", I get the following error:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value "foo_Table_1" to type Table.
Details:
    Value=foo_Table_1
    Type=[Type]
```

The error received makes sense since a string is not a table.

Is there a way I may parameterize the tables a merge query operates on?

Comment: does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60019455/excel-power-query-variables-for-table-name